# Segmentation fault when reading from multiple files

Tags: c++

I have this following program which gets the number of files from user, then the filename and reads the content of the file in to a priority queue. When I execute the program, after I enter the first filename it gives segmentation fault.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *filename;
    int fnum;

    cout<<"Number of files:"<<endl;
    cin>>fnum;

    int i;
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > pqi;
    for(i = 0; i<fnum;i++){
        cout <<"Enter Filename:"<<endl;
        cin>>filename;
        ifstream inFile(filename);
        long n;
        while(!inFile.eof()){
            inFile >> n;
            pqi.push(n);
        }
        inFile.close();
        inFile.clear();
    }
    while(!pqi.empty()) {
        cout << pqi.top() << ' ';
        pqi.pop();
    }
}
```

Not able to figure out why.

Comment: May I suggest editing the post and fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: Have you tried with a debugger?

Comment: If this is a homework, you have to explicitly tag it `homework`.

Comment: no this is not a homework, I am studying for my finals, this is a question I had encountered in past papers. I realize my folly, I must be over working. Thanks for the help Hossein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `char*` definition. You just define a pointer and don't allocate any memory to it. You have to allocate memory to it using the `new` keyword:

```
char *filename = new char[256];
//... rest of your code ...
//When you no longer need filename (usually at the end of the code)
//you have to free the memory used by it manually:
delete[] filename;
```

In this simple case you can also use a static array:

```
char filename[256];
//No need to delete[] anything in this way.
```

Both of the above ways allocate a fixed amount of memory to `filename`, which means if user enters a file name longer than 256 bytes in the above examples we encounter a *buffer overflow*. You can use `string` type which automatically does the memory management for you and is easy to use:

```
#include <string>
string filename;
cin >> filename;
```

Comment: You probably meant *buffer overflow* instead of under run.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have

```
char *filename;
```

And later you use

```
cin>>filename;
```

You have simply no space allocated for the filename, so the input is written into some undefined memory. Either define `filename` as an array of char, or use `std::string`.